# How can I compare two columns for similarity in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one column that called 'message' and includes several data such as fund_no, detail, keywords. This column is in table called 'trackemails'.

I have another table, called 'sendemails' that has a column called 'Fund_no'.

I want to retrieve all data from 'trackemail' table that the column 'message'  contains characters same as 'Fund_no' in 'trackemails' Table.

I think If I want to check the equality, I would write this code:

```
select
case when t.message=ts.fund_no then 1 else 0 end
from trackemails t, sendemails s
```

But, I do want something like below code:

```
select
case when t.message LIKE ts.fund_no then 1 else 0 end
from trackemails t, sendemails s
```

I would be appreciate any advice to how to do this:

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.

Comment: "I have one column that called 'message' and includes several data" **There's your problem.** Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear Check SQL [CHARINDEX() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp). This function finds a string in another string and returns int for the position they match. Like

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('ha','Elham')  
-- Returns: 3
```

And as you need:

```
 SELECT * 
        ,(SELECT * 
         FROM sendemail 
         WHERE CHARINDEX(trackemails.Message,sendemail.Fund_No)>0 )
 FROM trackemails
```

For more information, If you want something much better for greater purposes, you can use **[Fuzzy Lookup Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/fuzzy-lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-2017)** in SSDT **SSIS**. This Component gives you a new column in the output which shows the **Percentages of similarity** of two values in two columns.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM trackemails tr
   INNER JOIN sendemail se on tr.Message like '%' + se.Fund_No + '%'
```